# Yii2 RBAC Permission Own post

Tags: php, yii2

I would like give permission update/delete post/category for author who created post/category

I don't know, what I must give here as second parameter. I tried:

```
$post=new Post();

       if (Yii::$app->user->can('updatePost',['Post'=>$post]))
```

but gets error   Getting unknown property: common\models\Post::createdBy

My Class AuthorRule:

```
class AuthorRule extends Rule
{
public $name = 'isAuthor';

/**
 * @param string|integer $user the user ID.
 * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated with
 * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
 * @return boolean a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
 */
public function execute($user, $item, $params)
{
    return isset($params['Post']) ? $params['Post']->CreatedBy->id == $user : false;
}
}
```

UPDATE:

- [Post Model](http://pastebin.com/c7QknZJu)
- [RBAC Controller](http://pastebin.com/6NQ02Rp7)
- [AuthorRule](http://pastebin.com/N22uhJYv)
- [AuthItem Table](http://gyazo.com/f02bb3609a293c72a4fba97442fafdc8)
- [AuthItemChild Table](http://gyazo.com/4eed2e59a580ddcba21f0420b765cca8)
- [Auth Assignment](http://gyazo.com/87d0199b6a8862f85ed386fa0d30f613)

Comment: Why you wanto set the second parameter in  `->can(....)`?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the right thing, passing the object to the rule.

Are you sure your `Post` model actually has the `createdBy` property? In your other piece of code you have `CreatedBy`.

Most likely that typo is the problem, or your `Post` model does not have that field, or it's called differently (`created_by`?)

Oh, one more thing, if `CreatedBy` is a relation, and the object does not exist, trying to get its attribute (`id`) will produce an error. Try something like `if (isset($params['Post']->CreatedBy) && $params['Post']->CreatedBy->id == $user)`.

Comment: I changed method execute but now gets exception- access denied , why?  id_user is my FK in table post.

     `public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        return isset($params['post']) ? $params['post']->id_user == $user :       false;
    }`

  So Check 

      `$post=new Post();
        if (Yii::$app->user->can('updatePost',['post'=>$post]))`

Comment: Please be more specific - access to what is denied?

Comment: access denited because,  user not have  permission, but in database have all permision to update own post.
Post Model


http://pastebin.com/c7QknZJu

RBAC Controller 
http://pastebin.com/6NQ02Rp7

AuthorRule

http://pastebin.com/N22uhJYv

AuthItem Table
https://gyazo.com/f02bb3609a293c72a4fba97442fafdc8

AuthItemChild Table 

https://gyazo.com/4eed2e59a580ddcba21f0420b765cca8

Auth Assignment

https://gyazo.com/87d0199b6a8862f85ed386fa0d30f613

Comment: Is current user assigned a role? I see you have assigned `Author` role to user id 2. Are you trying to access the post when you are logged in as user id 2?

Comment: Yea, i tried update own  post when  I was logged   as  user id 2 and  gets  access denied.  User  ID 1 (Admin) can update/create/delete all post and it work.

Comment: I suggest you find out if `AuthorRule` is actually being called when you are logged in as user 2. If it is, see which parameters are being passed into it.